# Javascript timer refresh and php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

I want to do after I clicked a button to start countdown and when the timer reaches 0 to execute a query to the database. I do timer JS (I do not know how much is correct, but it works), I am interested after reaching the end how to execute an SQL query? And also, I need at refresh the page timer continues to count down rather than start from scratch ..

This is what i make:

```
<div id='timer'></div>
var elapsed= "20";


function calcTimeLeft(numSec) {
    if (numSec <= 0) {
        window.location=window.location;
    }
    console.log(elapsed);
    var sec = numSec%60;
    var min = parseInt(numSec/60);
    if(min>60){
        var h = parseInt(min/60);
        min = min-h*60;
    }else{
        h=0;
    }
    min = (min<10?"0":"")+min;
    sec = (sec<10?"0":"")+sec
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Остава: "+h+" часа "+min+" минути "+sec+" секунди";
    setTimeout("calcTimeLeft("+(numSec-1)+");", 1000);
}
onLoad=calcTimeLeft(elapsed);
```

Comment: You need ajax to call a php page which will run your query

Comment: Change `window.location=window.location;` to `$("#result").load("update.php",{"someparm":someJSVar});`